# C++ T4 TextTransforms and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm struggling to get T4 TextTransforms to work in a C++ proj.
Is it possible and if so how?

I have already added the following to the proj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VSToolsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0</VSToolsPath>
  <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
  <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and I also have

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

Any ideas how to make this work please?
When I build the project, the tt file is not processed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old issue, but maybe this can help someone. Open folder :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TextTemplating
```

and Change the Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets.targets file as follows:

Change the line

```
<Target Name="TransformDuringBuild" Condition=" $(TransformOnBuild)==true">
```

to

```
<Target Name="TransformDuringBuild" Condition=" $(TransformOnBuild)==true" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

(Optional) Delete the following lines:

```
 <BuildDependsOn>TransformDuringBuild;$(BuildDependsOn)</BuildDependsOn>
```